# Update just one gem with bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I use bundler to manage dependencies in my rails app, and I have a gem hosted in a git repository included as followed:

```
gem 'gem-name', :git => 'path/to/my/gem.git'
```

To update this gem, I execute `bundle update` but it also updates all the gem mentioned in Gemfile. So what is the command to update just one specific gem?

Answer (score 481, accepted):

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20141009095250/http://ilikestuffblog.com/2012/07/01/you-should-update-one-gem-at-a-time-with-bundler-heres-how/) you can find a good explanation on the difference between

*Update both gem and dependencies:*

```
bundle update gem-name
```

**or**

*Update exclusively the gem:*

```
bundle update --source gem-name
```

along with some nice examples of possible side-effects.

### Update

As @Tim's answer says, as of Bundler 1.14 the officially-supported way to this is with `bundle update --conservative gem-name`.

Comment: Be careful, "updating gem and dependencies" means updating rails itself if it is a dependency and you probably don't want that. *--source* will only update the gem specified as parameter. So it is better in most situations.

Comment: how to specify the version?

Comment: @OshanWisumperuma Specify the version in Gemfile or possibly Gemfile.lock prior to running these bundle commands

Answer (score 199):

The way to do this is to run the following command:

```
bundle update --source gem-name
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, I have a private gem and only needs to update the gem itself without updating the dependencies after I made some changes to the private gem.

Answer (score 65):

It appears that with newer versions of bundler (>= 1.14) it's:

```
bundle update --conservative gem-name
```

Comment: note: this command will update one gem without dependencies of it

Comment: As with the basic non-conservative `update`, multiple gem names can be specified. This is useful when you want to update a specific subtree of transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 25):

You simply need to specify the gem name on the command line:

```
bundle update gem-name
```

Comment: Strange. That's what `bundle help update` says to do. Which version of bundler are you using?

Comment: `bundle update gem-name` will update the gem and "any of its dependencies".

Answer (score 8):

`bundle update gem-name [--major|--patch|--minor]`

This also works for dependencies.

Comment: Is there a way to update it to a specific version? The `--major`, `--minor`, and `--patch` flags automatically upgrade it to the latest possible version.

Comment: You can specify a specific version in the Gemfile, i.e. 'x.y.z' rather than '~> x.y.z'

Answer (score 3):

I've used `bundle update --source` myself for a long time but there are scenarios where it doesn't work. Luckily, there's a gem called [`bundler-patch`](https://github.com/livingsocial/bundler-patch) which has the goal of fixing this shortcoming.

I also wrote a short [blog post](https://christoph.luppri.ch/articles/2016/05/14/how-to-conservatively-update-a-single-gem-with-bundler/) about how to use `bundler-patch` and why `bundle update --source` doesn't work consistently. Also, be sure to check out [a post](https://github.com/chrismo/bundler-source-hack) by chrismo that explains in great detail what the `--source` option does.

Answer (score 0):

`bundler update --source gem-name` will update the revision hash in Gemfile.lock which you can compare with the last commit hash of that git branch (master by default).

`GIT
  remote: git@github.com:organization/repo-name.git
  revision: c810f4a29547b60ca8106b7a6b9a9532c392c954`

can be found at `github.com/organization/repo-name/commits/c810f4a2` (I used shorthand 8 character commit hash for the url)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a single gem to a specific version:

1. change the version of the gem in the Gemfile
2. `bundle update`

```sh
> ruby -v
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-darwin19]
> gem -v
3.0.3
> bundle -v
Bundler version 2.1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

If nothing happens with `bundle update gem-name` it's maybe due to having as a global config `do not touch lock files`, you can disable this:
`bundle config set frozen false`