# Rails: You have already activated rake 10.3.1, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.2.2 (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake

Here is my error:

```
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 10.3.1, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.2.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in `block in setup'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `setup'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/Desktop/Ripelist-Classifieds/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/Desktop/Ripelist-Classifieds/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/Desktop/Ripelist-Classifieds/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/Users/AaronWilliamson/Desktop/Ripelist-Classifieds/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/Desktop/Ripelist-Classifieds/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/AaronWilliamson/Desktop/Ripelist-Classifieds/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I can't run any rake tasks and this seems to be the root of all my other problems. It wasn't like this a couple days ago when I was running rake commands. Can anyone explain what's going on here and how to get my app back on track? I've hit a wall. Also, `bundle exec` doesn't fix the root of the problem for me. I never had to do that in the past and it's still not working now.

Comment: Run bundle update

Comment: How did you use bundle exec ? You should run rake task like this: `bundle exec rake namespace:task_name`

Comment: That is a different issue. This might help https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2991

Comment: I've already looked at that link and it provides no solution.

Comment: `bundle update` actually did more harm than good. It reverted a lot of gem dependencies to very early versions.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**EDIT 2:**
You should look at `bundle update` and change your workflow a little. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263150/update-just-one-gem-with-bundler) for further assistance.

---

**Original answer**

This is a simple issue which happens when your gemset has a rake version that is newer than the version number your `Gemfile.lock` mentions.

As is mentioned in the error message, you can use `bundle exec` to get things working.

My solution in such cases is to just remove `Gemfile.lock` if I am not too worried other gem versions and their endless dependencies. Otherwise, you can try just removing the one line in `Gemfile.lock` which talks about the version of rake. run `bundle install` and the world should be a happy place again. (*edit 2*: Run `bundle update --source` instead of this. Don't do this.)

PS: Try using [gemsets and organising your gems with rvm](http://rvm.io/gemsets/basics) for different projects.

**Edit**

I prefer using [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) now for managing installations and all gems for a project reside in `vendor/bundle` using `bundle install --path` option. Later scope every gem command with `bundle exec`.

Hence, `rails s` becomes `bundle exec rails s`. A little more typing is, in my opinion, better if it means that things will remain clean and conflicts such as this one don't happen.

Comment: where could i see the _version number of_ `Gemfile.lock`. can i ?

Comment: @Vinay: There is no version number of `Gemfile.lock` as such. You should look in the file `$PROJ_ROOT/Gemfile.lock`. Search for text `rake`. Somewhere there should be a line which mentions a version number. That should be your clue as to what to do next.

Comment: Downvoting. You shouldn't break Bundler by removing or altering `Gemfile.lock`. Instead, use `bundle update` or something.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser I agree that this is a "bad hack" per say but the situation here says that you have two versions of rake installed in the same bundle. So, you might have done something wrong like maybe, not separating out your bundles properly as per projects and the dependencies of 2 of them clashed. However, I would love to know another solution. Please provide a link if you find one.

Comment: @manu29.d I haven't figured out a better solution than `bundle update` either, but I wouldn't ever even consider a bad hack like this.

Comment: In my particular case, that wasn't an option, since a `bundle update` would mean that a lot of my gems would update and some of them didn't have bac kwards compatibility with others that I was using. Plus the code would also break and certain points. Hence, this solution in my case was what I could come up with

Comment: @manu29.d That shouldn't be an obstacle to `bundle update`: just specify the appropriate versions in the `Gemfile`.

Answer (score 45):

A simple solution that worked for me is to simply run `bundle update rake`.

Comment: That solved it for me as well! My problem was "You have already activated rake 11.3.0, but your Gemfile requires rake 11.2.2".

Comment: This does work to remove the need to prepend bundle exec, however, as a word of warning as in my case, all the updates broke other issues I did not want to deal with so I `git checkout --Gemfile.lock` to go back and just live with the rake version discrepancy.

Comment: This is the correct answer for the similar error I'm experiencing and also the simplest.

Answer (score 39):

You can use `rubygems-bundler` to solve this. Run the following commands:

`$ gem install rubygems-bundler`
`$ gem regenerate_binstubs`

Then try your rake again.

Comment: praise JEEZUZ thanks the LAWD - but i have a question: what is the actualy problem - what is going on - and how did rubygems-bundler solve it?

Comment: Why doesn't bundler handle this? I will be pushing this out to other devs, I can't be expecting them to go through all this manual rigmarole

Comment: This works for me without changing `Gemfile.lock`. I installed my Ruby 2.3.4 via rvm and my warning was `Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 10.4.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.3.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.`. Thanks.

Comment: This did not work for me. Instead this gave me new error:

` ArgumentError: Trying to register Bundler::GemfileError for status code 4 but Bundler::GemfileError is already registered `

I don't know how I can solve it anymore.

Answer (score 30):

I had a similar issue and I was skeptical about removing a line from my `Gemfile.lock`, it seemed hacky and the inconvenience of prepend `bundle exec` to every rake command was not an option either. I fixed this by first going into my `Gemfile.lock` to see what version of `rake` was there (in my case it was 11.1.2). My thought was to uninstall `rake` and install this version. Running `gem uninstall rake` gave this output:

> Select gem to uninstall:
>
> 1. rake-10.5.0
> 2. rake-11.1.1
> 3. rake-11.1.2
> 4. rake-11.2.2
> 5. rake-11.3.0
> 6. All versions

I uninstalled both `rake-11.2.2` and `rake-11.3.0`. That fixed my problem

Comment: This was perfect.. simple, easy and makes sense!!

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me as well, not rake but for json gem. Same issue.

Comment: I ran this and it uninstalled all of my rake versions, however then I ran @Ishpreet's suggestion and it solved my problem. Ishpreet's solution alone however did not work for me.

Answer (score 11):

Use this:

```
gem install rake -v "version-you-want"
```

Comment: Brilliant. That command fixed the issue. I tried the ones above with no luck. Thanks

Comment: Also required `gem uninstall rake` in my case

Answer (score 3):

My error message:

```sh
~ $ rake db:migrate                                                                                                                                                                            [2.6.5][10:21:00]
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 12.3.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 13.0.1. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.
/Users/torvalds/workspace/ekohe/whitespace/config/boot.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/torvalds/workspace/ekohe/whitespace/config/application.rb:3:in `require_relative'
/Users/torvalds/workspace/ekohe/whitespace/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/torvalds/workspace/ekohe/whitespace/Rakefile:6:in `require_relative'
/Users/torvalds/workspace/ekohe/whitespace/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am using the `rbenv` to manage my Ruby environment.

My global Ruby version is as know as the `default` Ruby version is `2.7.1`, because I set it as `rbenv global 2.7.1`. However, my rake under Ruby 2.7.1 is `12.3.2`

```sh
~ $ rake --version

rake, version 12.3.2
```

My project Ruby version is `2.6.5`. however, my rake under Ruby 2.6.5 in my project is `13.0.1`

```sh
~ $ bundle exec rake --version

rake, version 13.0.1
```

so I have to uninstall global rake

```sh
~ $ gem uninstall rake
```

and reinstall it back

```sh
~ $ gem install rake

Fetching rake-13.0.1.gem
Successfully installed rake-13.0.1
1 gem installed
```

it works! ~~~

I'm not sure whether it will have an influence on other projects. However, so far it works.

Answer (score 2):

According to this solution (that worked for me) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23668399/4260090

You can solve it by using `rubygems-bundler`

Type these commands in your terminal :

```
$ gem install rubygems-bundler
$ gem regenerate_binstubs
```

It should work now

Answer (score 1):

Try to install nodejs, this was solved my problem.

If you're on ubuntu run this command.

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: But What is the problem if you don't have Nodejs? What exactly coursed the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I tried another way which is delete `Gemfile.lock` then run `bundle install`. After that I run `rake db:migrate`. And everything works fine.

Although I don't think remove `Gemfile.lock` is bad practice, but may be; who know.

Comment: everybody please aware that might kill your gemfile. please make sure to have a backup in case you can't resolve things to correct versions afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Go in the `Gemfile.lock`, find the rake file and update the version there.

I got this error:

> Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 11.2.2, but your
>   Gemfile requires rake 11.1.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command
>   may solve this.

What I did was to change the version of rake in the `Gemfile.lock` from: 
`rake (11.1.2)` to `rake (11.2.2)`.

Everything worked fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on earlier answers this is a simple issue which happens when your gemset has a rake version that is newer than the version number your `Gemfile.lock` mentions.

The easiest way to debug this is to run `bundle update`.

The other ways could be to remove `Gemfile.lock` and running `bundle install` or simply deleting the line in `Gemfile.lock` that corresponds to the rake version and try `bundle install`. But this might sometimes corrupt the Gemfile. I would prefer the first method because it is the safest and the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error:

You have already activated rake 12.0.0, but your Gemfile requires rake 11.3.0. Prepending "bundle exec" to your command may solve this.

I solved it by running `bundle update`

this updated the rake version to my activated rake version and everything worked I hope that works for you!

Answer (score 0):

I meet the similar problem.
My solution is change the line of rake version "gem 'rake', '~> 10.3'" in file Gemfile, delete Gemfile.lock and run 'bundler install', the new Gemfile.lock will show the new version 10.3.1. Then everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue:

**Here's my solution**:

**Solution 1**:

This solution works a lot of the time, simply update the gem causing the issue, say the gem is `rack`

```
bundle update rack
```

**Solution 2**:

In some cases **Solution 1** may not work, and you will need to edit your `Gemfile.lock` file.

Simply, open your `Gemfile.lock` file and then change the version to the update requested.

In my case, the gem was `rack`, I had `rack 2.0.7` defined in my `Gemfile.lock` file, but my application required `rack 2.1.2`, I simply had to modify it to `rack 2.1.2` in the `Gemfile.lock` file.

I then had to uninstall the previous version of rack which is `rack 2.0.7`

```
 gem uninstall rack -v 2.0.7
```

And finally installed the new gem in production

```
bundle install --without development test
```

**Solution 3**:

In very rare cases **Solution 1** and **Solution 2** may not work, and you will need to edit your `Gemfile` before updating the gem.

In my case, the gem was `puma`, I had `puma ~> 3.11` defined in my `Gemfile`, but my application required `puma ~> 4.3.1`. At this point running `bundle update puma` and editing my `Gemfile.lock` file didn't work, since `puma ~> 3.11` version specified in the Gemfile would not allow an update to `puma ~> 4.3.1`.

I simply had to change the version of puma in the Gemfile to `puma ~> 4.3.1` and then ran the command.

```
bundle update puma
```

**Solution 4**:

If the version of rake that your Gemfile requires is less than the rake version activated, and you do not want to update rake, then you can as well run the command below to remove the version of rake that is activated:

```
gem list rake
gem uninstall rake
```

and then select the version of rake you want to uninstall.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed by simply prepending `bundle exec` as

```
"bundle exec rake db:create" or migrate
```