# Cannot load gem during gem pristine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ubuntu-14.04

I am using rails on my local host and have recently been confronted with the following message.

```
Warning: You're using Rubygems 1.8.23 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all` for better startup performance.
```

Sounds fair enough, however when I run the suggested command, it hangs on installing the cairo gem with the following message.

```
Cached gem for cairo-1.12.8 not found, attempting to fetch...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
    Cannot load gem at [/usr/share/rubygems-integration/1.9.1/cache/cairo-1.12.8.gem] in     /home/me/
```

What might be going on here?

Comment: did you upgrade your rubygems bu `sudo gem update system`

Comment: @RajarshiDas Thanks for the reply! Got a "nothing to update" response and the error still persists.

Comment: I found this forum post when trying to solve another problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/23668399/2540204 From this, I ran `gem install rubygems-bundler` and `gem regenerate_binstubs` This got rid of the error `Warning: You're using Rubygems 1.8.23 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run 'gem pristine --all' for better startup performance.`  But when I run `gem pristine --all`, I still get the error regarding the cairo gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all I ended up finding a post that recommended I just reinstall ruby again.  Seeing no other choice I did a `rvm uninstall ruby` then a `rvm install ruby` and set everything else back up and it went well.  Unsatisfying but true :-P

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your rubygems to the 2.1.0 or newer versions. The newest version is currently 2.4.5 it was updated Dec. 3rd 2014.  Try this link to update. https://rubygems.org/gems/rubygems-update

Comment: Hi Christopher, thanks for the reply.  I installed the gem but the error still persists.

Comment: Make sure that you run bundle install deployment.