# Rake does not run for older Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I try to run `rake routes` on an older Rails application, then I got this:

```
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 11.1.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.4.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.
```

So I tried `bundle exec`, it works.

But how can I change my Gemfile so that I don't have to `bundle exec`,
rake 10.4.2 is not explicitly in my Gemfile.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Already activated rake version different than what Gemfile requires prevents rake commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287357/already-activated-rake-version-different-than-what-gemfile-requires-prevents-rak)

Answer (score 0):

Your current gemset has rake version `11.1.2`, but your `Gemfile.lock` requires to use older version (namely `10.4.2`).

If updating your project gems versions won't break your project, you can delete `Gemfile.lock` file and then run `bundle install` to create a new one. Then, the "problem" should be fixed.

Comment: yes @Uzbekjon is right, try deleting Gemfile.lock if your app is currently under development. Otherwise uninstall `rake 11.1.2` and try `bundle` once more.