# Your bundle is locked to rake (12.0.0), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile, gemfile.lock

I get the following error message when starting the rails server:

> Your bundle is locked to rake (12.0.0), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that means the author of rake (12.0.0) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a different version of rake (12.0.0) that hasn't been removed in order to install.

I specified `gem 'rake', '12.0.0'` in the gemfile but that doesn't fix it. I tried `bundle update rake`, deleting the `Gemfile.lock` and generating it with `bundle exec bundle install`. I also prepended `bundle exec1 to al my commands which does nothing.

My Gemfile.lock already specifies rake version 12.0.0, and there are no other versions installed.

See my gemfile:
http://pastebin.com/L4tVFWz9

And rakefile:
http://pastebin.com/K7p2ajsE

I tried the solutions suggested in [Already activated rake version different than what Gemfile requires prevents rake commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287357/already-activated-rake-version-different-than-what-gemfile-requires-prevents-rak)

Comment: try: bundle update

Comment: if you tried the answers in above link, 
Remove the `vendor/bundle` directory and run `bundle install` to rebuild it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different methods to solve this issue,

**Step1:**

```
gem install rubygems-bundler
gem regenerate_binstubs
```

**Step2:**

Remove the vendor/bundle directory.

Run `bundle install` to rebuild it

**Step3:**

Try, `gem update bundler`

[Here is a link where the issue got solved. Check this is very useful](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/5068)

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about Step 2! Thanks so much.

Comment: I'm confused. You offered 1 method through 3 steps. What's the other method of doing thihs?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

gem install rubygems-bundler

gem regenerate_binstubs

Answer (score 1):

Not really a fundamental solution, but if you really have to run some Rails commands urgently and needs a temporary fix, try `bundle exec rails c` rather than `bin/rails c`.

Answer (score 0):

Enter command :-

```html
bundle update rake
```