# You have already activated minitest 5.5.1, but your Gemfile requires minitest 4.7.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, minitest

rails server doesn't work with me, when I run `rails s -p 3005`, I got the following error:

```
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
/home/badrit-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:33:in `block in setup': You have already activated minitest 5.5.1, but your Gemfile requires minitest 4.7.5. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /home/badrit-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
    from /home/badrit-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
    from /home/badrit-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/badrit-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require'
    from /home/badrit-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `rescue in require'
    from /home/badrit-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /home/badrit-user/work/seeloz_mobile/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/badrit-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:106:in `require'
    from /home/badrit-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:106:in `require'
    from /home/badrit-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@seeloz_mobile/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:42:in `block in exec_app_rails'
    from /home/badrit-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@seeloz_mobile/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:32:in `loop'
    from /home/badrit-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@seeloz_mobile/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:32:in `exec_app_rails'
    from /home/badrit-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@seeloz_mobile/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/cli.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/badrit-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:58:in `require'
    from /home/badrit-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:58:in `require'
    from /home/badrit-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@seeloz_mobile/gems/railties-4.1.8/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/badrit-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@seeloz_mobile/bin/rails:23:in `load'
    from /home/badrit-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@seeloz_mobile/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

And I checked my Gemfile.lock, I have already `minitest (4.7.5)`.

It's weird, If I run this `bundle exec rails s -p 3005`, it's working, so Why this occurred ?

What's the solution to fix this issue ? (to run it using `rails s`)

Comment: have you tried `bundle exec rails s -p 3005` as it mentioned in your error message?

Comment: Try using `bundle install -—binstubs` and then run your app using `rails s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you can see from error message `Using bundle exec may solve this.`

```
bundle exec rails s -p 3005
```

> It's weird, If I run this `bundle exec rails s -p 3005`, it's working,
>   so Why this occurred ?

Running a command with `bundle exec` at begin, launch gem what installed with a Gemfile from app directory, without `bundle exec` it is run gem what installed in to the system. As you can see you have success installed `minitest 5.5.1` in system and `minitest 4.7.5` in the Gemfile.

[`Ref`](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/wiki/Understanding-binstubs#project-specific-binstubs)

Comment: I agree with you, can I upgrade minitest in Gemfile to 5.5.1 instead of 4.7.5 ? .. it's typed in Gemfile.lock but not in Gemfile, it's installed as dependencies of another gem

Comment: [sure, look this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263150/update-just-one-gem-with-bundler)

Answer (score 1):

If you’re not using bundler’s binstubs with RVM integration yet, you should give it a try!

This means you don’t have to type `bundle exec` ever again.

Setup:

- One time, run `chmod +x $rvm_path/hooks/after_cd_bundler`
- Once for each project, run `bundle install -—binstubs`